# How to reference one maven project from another maven project?

Tags: java, maven

I have an in-development library project (module by IntelliJ definition) that i want to reference from other projects. How would i go about to reference that project in other projects ?

Comment: Very similar to a question I asked a couple of years ago when I was learning Maven: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2511908/how-can-i-make-one-maven-module-depend-on-another

Answer (score 5):

you can use whether Dependency or module tags in pom.xml of your project.
Depends on what you trying to do.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.mysubpro</groupId>
        <artifactId>myproject</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

Or

```
<modules>
    <module>myproject</module>
</modules>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `mvn install` goal. This will install your library to your local repository. Link to [Maven Install Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/usage.html). Once it is done you can have a dependency to it in your other projects.