# How to properly "export" an entity from one maven project to another?

Tags: java, maven, entity, maven-module

I have a project with a regular structure.

```
project_a/
├─ src/
│  ├─ main/
│  │  ├─ java/
│  │  │  ├─ com/
│  │  │  │  ├─ myproject/
│  │  │  │  │  ├─ model/
│  │  │  │  │  ├─ Application.java
├─ pom.xml
```

The `com.myproject.model` package contains a large number of entity classes.

I need to create a new maven project that will use these entities.

```
project_a/
├─ project_b/
│  ├─ ...
│  ├─ pom.xml
├─ ....
├─ pom.xml
```

What is the best way to do this?
From my ideas, this is to take the entity into a separate **module** (in general, to make a modular project).

And can I just import the `com.myproject.model` package into `project_b` as if it were a projcet_b package. What are the consequences of this?

Comment: See [java - How to reference one maven project from another maven project? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12444413/how-to-reference-one-maven-project-from-another-maven-project)

Comment: The simplest way is to create a multi module project which contains at least two modules the model part and the rest of your application. Afterwards you can use that model project in other projects...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve that one of the way is to make the entity into a separate maven module. If you are developing locally when you run the command mvn clean install it will generare the snapshot in the .m2 repository. If not , you can use tools like artifactory to store your dependencies somewhere and pull them when needed, but much more effort is needed in this case.

Another way could also be to import the JAR of the entity in your project.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The simplest and most reliable solution turned out to be to put entities in a separate maven module, thank you.